# What happens if I clone into a directory that is in use?

Tags: git

Assume that I have a directory `os` with my project file. Can I clone with git into that directory e.g. `$ git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2 os` and get the mix of files from the repo and my existing files or must the directory that I clone into not exist and be created by git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide an empty directory or run the clone command `git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2` inside the `os` directory but git will create a new directory for the libgit2 repo with the same name  .
I think you want to add a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) `git submodule add https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2`

Comment: Your ref to submodules is the key.   As long as that _is_ what the OP wants, he's in good shape.  What is not good, is if he wants to operate with files from a repo, and other files that are not managed.   That just isn't a good idea.

Comment: I agree you can't mix files from different repo inside the same directory. This is a bad a proach because the goal is to manage each repo independently

Answer (score 1):

As git in general is very careful to never unintentionally destroy files my feeling tells me this isn't possible and wouldn't be a good idea. But let's try:

```
$ mkdir p1
$ echo 'hi' > p1/foo.txt
$ cd p1/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/joern/coding/git/tmp/p1/.git/
$ git add foo.txt
$ git commit -m'init'
[master (root-commit) ad640a7] init
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 foo.txt
$ cd ..
$ mkdir p2
$ echo 'hallo' > p2/bar.txt
$ git clone p1 p2
fatal: destination path 'p2' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

So unsurprisingly this doesn't work. If your current `os` is a git directory you're probably after [Raulucco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30616845/1423333). If you just want to contribute your `os` files to the upstream repository, I'd recommend to clone your lib into a new directory and then copy all the files from the old one over it. That way the files in the clone are in the git repo and you can undo things if they go wrong:

```
$ mv os os.bak
$ git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2 os
$ rsync -avPi os.bak/ os/
$ # review the os directory before finally doing
$ rm -r os.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

For the syntax that you provided,  should be an empty directory. I used a "dao" repository that I had for exemplification:

```
D:\sites-personal
λ mkdir dao

D:\sites-personal
λ cd dao\

D:\sites-personal\dao
λ touch file.txt

D:\sites-personal\dao
λ cd ..

D:\sites-personal
λ git clone git@myorigin/dao.git dao
fatal: destination path 'dao' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```